# Why does the flask app that I have overwrite the previous data within the text file?

Tags: python

this might be a simple file write error but I am quite confused as to why my program - upon receiving a request and processing the data, overwrites the previous information within the text file. Is there a clear reason as to why it is not appending new data in the text file and is instead simply overwriting old data? Since this is the case, how would I go about appending new data to a text file output?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

SERVERDATA = open("PLAYERGATHERDATA.txt", "wt")

@app.route('/', methods =['POST'])
def post():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.data)
            datastr = str(request.data)
            dataclean = datastr[1:].replace('\\r', '').strip("'").replace('\\n','\n')
            with open("PLAYERGATHERDATA.txt", "wt") as SERVERDATA:
                SERVERDATA.write(dataclean)
            return 'FINISHED'
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port="8000")
```

Edit: I've found that appending the file solved the issue. So for the future I'll watch out for appending vs wt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using text append access mode mode, when you open the file, like:

```
with open("PLAYERGATHERDATA.txt", "a") as SERVERDATA:
```

On top of this, you don't need this statement above your Flask route:

```
SERVERDATA = open("PLAYERGATHERDATA.txt", "wt")
```

Access mode "append" will automatically create the file for you if it does not exist, and if it does, it will append the specified text to it, without overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to push back data to your file, you should use append mode for it.

Write mode 'w' erase the previous data of the file and insert new data while append mode don't erase previous data, it append new data with previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a text file is usually in this format

`file_object = open(filename, mode)`

Using "w" as the mode, opens file for writing. If file does not exist, it creates a new file. If file exists it truncates the file.

Using "a", opens the file in append mode. If file does not exist, it creates a new file.

You should try

`with open("PLAYERGATHERDATA.txt", "a") as SERVERDATA:`

Just to add, there is no difference between "a" and "at" or "w" and "wt" since text mode is the default.